# What is the best way to implement a function that performs a task periodically in python3.x?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, event-handling, python-multithreading, celerybeat

I am trying to build a small application which requires me to implement a timer function that checks whether a file(there are only 2 files) has changed or not every 3 seconds and this must run in parallel to the rest of the code(This clearly gives me the idea of a new thread).

There exists a celery-beat module in python which might help me achieve this, but it seems a very heavy framework for such a small application, which is why I want to avoid it.

I can also implement it using threading.Timer and threading.Event, but as per my understanding, it will be a waste of one good thread just to achieve a simple task.

Can anyone help me with a light weight tool that can help me solve this problem?

Feel free to correct me if you think my understandings are incorrect and help me understand anything that i am missing here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Without answering your actual question, [this package called watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) is relatively lightweight as far as I know and might be of use to you.

Comment: thanks a lot @jrbergen. This is what i wanted.